# Create a list of items within 'var response'

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var request = new GeocodingRequest();
request.Address = postcode;
request.Sensor = "false";
var response = GeocodingService.GetResponse(request);

var result = response.Results. ...?
```

I'd very much like to get result as a list, but I can't seem to convert it.  I know I can do something like `response.Results.ToList<string>();`, but have had no luck.

Can anyone help please :)

Comment: What library are you using? Google is not being very useful, since this is a very common term.

Comment: What is the type of `response`? Maybe a link to an API page might be useful. Are you using WCF?

Comment: @Mike Caron, thanks for the message. How did you know it was a Google library? :) Very clever.  The library is this excellent library: http://gmaps.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Graham Clark, thanks for the message.  That was my problem - I kept assuming `var response` could be, or was a type and therefore was trying to convert it. Andrey answered correctly - despite its complete simplicity! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @dooburt: I had no idea that it was a google thing. I meant I tried to search for the library _using_ google. :)

Comment: @Mike, +1 just for the intuitive guess nevertheless :)  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you *can* just use:

```
GeocodingResult[] results = response.Results;
```

or

```
List<GeocodingResult> results = response.Results.ToList();
```

If you want a list of *strings*, you'll need to decide how you want to convert each result into a string. For example, you might use:

```
List<string> results = response.Results
                               .Select(result => result.FormattedAddress)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: @dooburt: Of course all of these work with `var` instead of the explicit type, too.

Comment: can we use "Dynamic" in this scenario? Please let me know.

Comment: @Sandeep: Well you *could* use `dynamic`, but I can't see why you'd want to.

Answer (score 2):

It is defined as:

```
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public GeocodingResult[] Results { get; set; }
```

if you want to make it list call: `response.Results.ToList()`.

But why do you want to make it list? You can insert items into list, but I don't think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

assuming response.Results is IEnumerable, just make sure System.Linq is available as a namespace and say response.Results.ToList()